# Does it make sense to hoard on ripples like bitcoins?

Tags: ripple, speculation

Total number of bitcoins that will ever exist are 21 million and are deflated.

Ripples are pre-mined 100 billion. Would hoarding 30000 XRP now will get me a profit in the future from a speculation point of view? Also, I heard, XRP will be destroyed in each transaction.

Comment: Hi Medicine! A question that require answers to be very speculative is usually not a good fit for StackEchange. I would recommend that this question is closed as there is no good answer to "Would hoarding 30000 XRP now will get me a profit in the future".

Comment: Answer/observation: It certainly made sense to hoard them for the last 2 months...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is both useful and scarce then it'll be worth something and a market for it will emerge. Ripples are more scarce than bitcoins (absolute numbers dont matter while quantity of bitcoins continues to grow, quantity of XRPs is basically constant). The question is: how fast will ripples' usefulness grow ? Since ripples serve a lot of indispensable roles within the Ripple network AND are the ONLY asset in that network with no counterparty risk, I believe they will be very very useful and will therefore appreciate a lot.